# Querying attachments in apex class

Tags: attachment

We have a custom object.
In the notes and attachments related list of this custom object we have uploaded few pdf and ms-word files (each of them of size < 5 mb)
we are not able to access the attachments by soql query inside apex class.

Further even in workbench a simple query `'SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment'` returns 0 records.

Comment: Did you save as attachment or as chatter feed item? Try 'Select Id, ContentFileName From FeedItem'.

Comment: We saved it as attachment. We added a note as well and uploaded it.  For testing, we added a note to the same object and the query SELECT Id, body FROM Note returned the record. But still no luck with attachments

Comment: I've never seen that before. This works fine for me. You didn't mark the attachments as 'private', did you?

Comment: Try `SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId,ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'YourRecordId'` it's possible you have `Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments` enabled for your org.

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy. You are correct. In our org, the files uploaded to the attachments related list were uploaded as salesforce files. We unchecked the check-box and now the query works fine.

Comment: @Oleksiy, please be sure to post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In Spring'16 release Salesforce introduced](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_files_notes_attachments_list.htm) `Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments` in Salesforce Files Settings:

> Files that you upload to the Notes & Attachments related list on records in Salesforce Classic are now Salesforce Files objects, rather than the old attachment objects. **A new org pref in Salesforce Files Settings controls this behavior, and is enabled by default for new orgs.**

The following SOQL query would allow you to get Ids of Files (Attachments) and New Notes related to the record `SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId,ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'YourRecordId'`